# How can I lower my "Templar Awareness" quicker?

Tags: assassins-creed-revelations

Raising your **Templar Awareness** (formerly known as notoriety) as too easy and lowering it is relatively difficult.

Before, any mischievous action raised it a bit like pickpocketing which wasn't too bad.  At least lowering it back down was pretty easy since there were plenty of ways to do so.  You could find wanted signs everywhere to rip down for a quick 25% reduction.  Bribing heralds lowered it 50%.  Assassinating officials dropped it down 75% but they only appeared if you have a lot of notoriety.

This time, pickpocketing doesn't raise your awareness anymore but purchasing places does (A LOT!) and there's a lot of places to buy.  It seems just about anything common that you do in the game will raise it.

To make things worse, there are very little opportunities to lower it now as far as I can see.  The wanted posters are gone now, heralds only lower it about 25% now but they're still not plentiful.  Officials don't appear very often anymore and they only reduce by 50%.

What are some ways I can lower my templar awareness down easier or faster?

Comment: If it matters, I pretty much just started the third sequence but I'm planning on unlocking everything I possibly can before proceeding with the story.

Comment: I totally agree that its far too hard to lower it again, but I also found that it didn't really matter. Yes they attack my towers, but if you only take it back when you need them its not a big problem. Plus the game makes you run all over town, so 90% of the time its a waste anyway

Comment: FWIW, Den Defenses are actually super easy (the first one with the Greek Fire was by far the hardest for me, the other siege engines are way easier to take out).  You need to do at least 3 for 100% sync anyway.  (I'm not sure what happens if you lock all your dens...maybe the first forced one counts?  You'd just have to repeat that mission, I guess.)

Comment: For the record, getting all master assassins locked in without doing any den defenses gives you credit for the challenge for free.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't really lower it any faster than just looking for notoriety lowering people whenever they show up (as you've noticed, there's only heralds and witnesses). It's more the fact that it works differently than notoriety in AC2/BH

Guards no longer care what your notoriety is (at least as far as I can tell) even when you're in the red.

The red seems to be meaningless except for one detail. As long as you're in the red, doing something that would raise your notoriety has a chance for one of your dens to come under attack, with more notorious things (like buying property) having a very high chance.

The idea is that once you hit the red, just don't buy anything or kill anyone until you've managed to become secret again, and you won't have to worry about ever being attacked again.

If you manage to get all of your dens a master assassin, then it won't matter if you're in the red as none of your dens can be attacked (I'm currently at 6/7 dens locked, so I'm not sure if this is true, but I'm guessing either it won't matter anymore, or your notoriety will be locked at 0 or something).

Comment: I have 7/7 dens locked and I can confirm notoriety still goes up, I don't know what happens when you reach max notoriety, though, I try to keep it low, just in case...

Comment: I noticed that it's the red-dotted guards that seems to care about the notoriety, not the yellow-dotted ones. It seems that notoriety was redefined in this game. It's more like, "the templars are looking for me and I'm doing actions that makes me more noticeable." It's too bad dyeing your clothes doesn't affect it though. Who are they to know that the red-clothed assassin and the green-clothed assassin are one in the same?

Comment: Ah, it should also be pointed out that it's now called *Templar Awareness* so it all makes sense.

Comment: @JohnoBoy: I just reached having 7 Master Assassins leaving all dens locked.  Even with a full awareness meter, they completely stopped attacking.  I pretty much have free reign on the city.